# $A =\{ 1/(n+1): n \in \mathbb N \} $ is a nowhere dense subset

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Prove that the set $A =\displaystyle \left \{ \frac{1}{n+1} : n \in \mathbb N \right \} $ is a nowhere dense subset of $\displaystyle{ \mathbb R }$.

I have think two ways but I can't finish it. Here it is

1. I tried to prove that $ \text{int} (\bar{A}) = \emptyset$. For this it is enough to prove that $ \bar A =\mathbb Q $ but I can't show this.
2. I tried to prove that every interval of $ \mathbb R$ contains a subinterval whose intersection with $A$ is the empty set.

Any help?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Kindly do not use `\displaystyle` in title as it breaks the layout of the list of questions

Comment: You want to prove that the closure of $A$ is a set that's not closed?

Comment: The closure of $A$ cannot be $\mathbb{Q}$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed while the closure of $A$ is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You couldn't prove that $\operatorname{cl}A=\Bbb Q$ because it's not true. Try proving instead that $\operatorname{cl}A=A\cup\{0\}$.

By the way, it's also possible to use your second approach: the key step is showing that if $0<x<1$, there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\frac1{n+2}<x\le\frac1{n+1}\;.$$

**Added:** If you've not already done so, **draw a picture**:

[image]

Comment: You're too fast!

Comment: Can you give some hint how to prove $\operatorname{cl}A=A\cup\{0\}$ ? And why is this the key using the second approach?

Comment: @passenger: I assume that you've no trouble proving that $0$ is a limit point of $A$. Let $x\in\Bbb R\setminus (A\cup\{0\})$. If $x<0$ or $x>1$ you should have no trouble finding an open interval around $x$ disjoint from $A$. If $0<x<1$, show that $$\frac1{n+2}<x<\frac1{n+1}$$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$. (Doing this should answer your other question for you as well.)

Comment: Done! Thank you very much for your time!